# Allow custom letter in input validation?

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I've this textbox:

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="InputValidation"/>
```

I want that the user can insert only digit and this symbol => `:`

I actually did this:

```
private void InputValidation(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

this allow only to insert the digit, if I press `:` I cannot see the symbol. How can I add this in the regex?

Comment: Just add it to your range of characters, so it becomes `[^0-9:]`

Comment: @MattBurland Nice trick, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets in regex are used to denote a range of characters to match (or, with the `^` not match). So all you need to do is add the `:` character:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9:]+");
```

Now if you wanted to make it so they can only add 1 (or some other number) of `:`, then it will get a little trickier to do, but in that case you might want to just validate once the user has finished typing and not while they are typing (because otherwise it becomes a real pain for the user).

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9:]+");
```

To clarify what this means :-

'^'  means 'not'.

'0-9' means 'from zero to nine'.

'+'  means 'one or more occurrences'.

[]  denotes 'the range of characters to match'.

But,since '0-9' and ':' is written between brackets, hence both of their multiple occurrences will be correct.

The above code is trying to search the words which do not contain digits and : .If it happens , then proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
[0-9\:]+$
```

This allows you to write numbers from 0 to 9, and the character `:`

Comment: No need for the `\\` character, by the way.